# On a remark of Langlands

Tags: differential-equations, langlands-conjectures, geometric-langlands

I'm been wondering about this for a while and hope someone can enlighten me.

In this interview of Robert Langlands's from 2010, on pg 21 (Question 8) he states "At one point, when fairly young, I read the book of Coddington and Levinson on ordinary differential equations and was taken with the topic of differential equations with irregular singular points. There are traces of this topic in the long letter to Weil about the Hecke theory. The same topic reappears in the “geometric Langlands
programme” over C, where it has quite a different flavour than in Coddington-Levinson, whose references will have been Poincare and G. D. Birkhoff. In its current guise it is little explored. I hope to find time to learn more about this before I am done."

(1) From having seen Edward Frenkel speak on dualities in physics and geometric Langlands, and from speaking to people far more familiar with all of the above topics than myself, I can guess that the link with geometric Langlands may be as follows:

ODEs with irregular singular points $\longleftrightarrow$
asymptotic series/resummation methods $\longleftrightarrow$
getting non-perturbative physical theories from perturbative ones $\longleftrightarrow$
the link with geometric Langlands, with the last correspondence as described say here https://arxiv.org/abs/0906.2747.
Is this accurate? Are there any insightful comments one would like to add?

(2) Even if the above has some semblance of truth, I am not sure about what the link is to the arithmetic Langlands program: "There are traces of this topic in the long letter to Weil about Hecke theory."

The second last sentence is fascinating - I have talked to other people who also think "In its current guise it is little explored" (which came as a big surprise to me - ODEs with singularities?!), but to think understanding this better might lead to insights into both versions of the Langlands program ((3) could it?) sounds very interesting.

P.S. That I shared the arxiv paper above should not be taken as an indication that I understand its contents with any amount of depth at all, though if you feel like assuming familiarity with technicalities in the geometric Langlands program will lead to a full answer, please go ahead (and provide references if you can!)

Comment: At the very least, the Casselman (-Milicic?) subrepresentation theorem for real reductive groups, improving Harish-Chandra's subquotient theorem, using an elaboration of Deligne's work on PDE, is an essential "local" result for the modern representation theory of real reductive groups, which, yes, is essential for a high-end viewpoint on automorphic forms, Langlands' programme, and such... Is this the sort of thing you're wanting to hear?

Comment: My guess is the comment has rather concrete meaning. The study of irregular singular points of ODE is more or less the study of $\mathcal{D}$-modules on the formal disk. The space of local Langlands parameters in geometric Langlands is a moduli space of $\mathcal{D}$-modules on the formal disk. So the study of singularities of ODE is the geometric counterpart of the study of ramification in the arithmetic setting.

Comment: I apologize for the delay in response. @dhy I think I gathered something similar from talking to people about the geometric Langlands side, but is there a more direct link to the arithmetic side? Langlands says "there are traces of this in the long letter to Weil about the Hecke theory" and I can't imagine this is what he was thinking of.
Even with geometric Langlands, does it not seem Langlands is referring to something more concrete, especially considering his views on the geometric theory after the Abel paper (please excuse my naivety if this is not so)?

Comment: @paulgarrett I'm afraid I'm too ignorant to say "what I want to hear", but again I think it's unlikely that this is what Langlands is referring to in the letter to Weil?

Comment: @WaleedQaisar, I cannot claim to truly know, but in those years Harish-Chandra had already been using various ideas about higher-rank/dimension analogues of "ODE with regular singular points", in his work going back to the 1950s. Apparently he left a large, unfinished manuscript on this (dunno whether it reached his collected works... I've tried to buy a copy, but they're out of print?), which in fact did not quite succeed in proving the more-general things he needed for his repn theory of semi-simple real Lie groups... [cont']

Comment: ... [cont'] but/and Langlands would have been aware of those ideas, whether completely proven or not. And, indeed, as you speculate, I doubt that people had in mind "geometric Langlands" in those days.

Comment: @WaleedQaisar Well, I am not sure what Langlands is referring to in his letter to Weil. Langlands only says that there are "traces of this topic", and I can imagine various ways to see traces (e.g. paul garrett's comments seem plausible to me) but it is certainly not front and center in his letter. That being said, I would say that the link I previously mentioned is very concrete...

Comment: ...The mention of "geometric Langlands" is a red herring. My suggestion boils down to the observation that, in some ways, arithmetic galois groups and (complex) differential galois groups behave similarly. This has been known at least since 1970. (I don't think Langlands had this in mind for his letter to Weil.) But I would be kind of shocked if Langlands was thinking of something else for the link he mentions to the geometric Langlands program. The moment you start thinking about ramification there you instantly run into the theory of irregular singularities.

Comment: Thank you! I would be very interested in any resources you recommend I look at.